# Retaining select box based values on page refresh

Tags: php, jquery

I have one form where in select box in which I have two options "oui" and "non":

- When "oui" is selected "hello" is displayed
- When "non" is selected "not valid" is displayed

My problem is when I refresh page after submitting form, "oui" or "non" is properly selected but not the value based on it like "hello" or "not valid"

here is some code

```
<p>choose option: <select name="opt" class="slct">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">--</option>
    <option value="oui">Oui</option>
    <option value="non">Non</option>
    </select>
</p>
<div id="oui" class="brandDiv">
  hello
</div>
<div id="non" class="brandDiv">
  not valid
</div>
```

and the jquery

```
function showhide() {
$("div.brandDiv").hide();
$("select.slct").bind('change', function() {
    $('div.brandDiv').hide();
    var targetId = $(this).val();
    $('div#' + targetId).show();
});
}
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: how are you refreshing the page? Through the submit of a form? Or just hitting refresh in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about adding, the following ?

```
$( function() {
    $("select.slct").each(
      function() {
        $('div.brandDiv').hide();
        var targetId = $(this).val();
        $('div#' + targetId).show();
      }
    );
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you just trigger() the change event on dom ready?

```
$("select.slct").trigger('change');
```

or

```
$("select.slct").change();
```

Or if I understand you correctly you have a function called showhide()

```
$(function(){  // <-- on dom ready
      showhide(); // <-- run function
});
```